# How to force SCons to use absolute path instead of relative in targets?

Tags: build, scons, absolute-path

I'm trying to build a project that uses `tsc` (TypeScript compiler) on Windows, and it seems like when SCons invokes the compiler, it invokes it in the wrong directory. Besides, the command it generates, despite my best effort uses relative paths instead of absolute ones, and fails, below is the code that does it:

```py
import os

sdk_sources = [] # some *.ts files

deployments_settings = [] # some more files

def prefix_file(file):
    return os.path.join(Dir('.').abspath, 'src', str(file))

def modify_targets(target, source, env):
    for x in source:
        print "source: %s" % str(x)
    return target, source

Tsc = Builder(
    action = 'tsc --target ES5 --out $TARGETS $SOURCES',
    suffix = '.js', src_suffix = '.ts', emitter = modify_targets)
env = Environment(BUILDERS = { 'Tsc' : Tsc },
                  BUILD_ROOT = Dir('.'),
                  ENV = { 'PATH' : os.environ['PATH'] })
env.Tsc(target = 'deploy/test', source = map(prefix_file, sdk_sources))
```

Here's what happens after I run it:

```
tsc --target ES5 --out deploy\test.js src\***.ts src\***.ts 
Error reading file "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\TypeScript\lib.d.ts": File not found
Error reading file "src\***.ts": File not found
*** repeated many times ***
scons: *** [deploy\test.js] Error 1
scons: building terminated because of errors.
```

PS. If I just run the generated command from the same directory, where SCons build starts, the build succeeds.

**EDIT:**

More info

```py
from subprocess import call

def name_of(file): return file.abspath

def tsc(source, target, env):
    call(['tsc', '--target', 'ES5', '--out', target[0].abspath] +
         map(name_of, source))

Tsc = Builder(action = tsc)
```

This builder works as expected.

Answer (score 2):

SCons is designed to build source files that are considered to be ***in*** the project structure. That means that that the source files must be in the same directory or a sub-directory relative to where the root level SConstruct script is located.

Sounds like what you are trying to do is build source files that are not in the project structure and that's why it is failing. The developers have talked about possibly changing this in future releases, but for now the only way around it is to put the source files in the project structure.

It may be helpful to you to know there is an option for specifying files relative to the root SConstruct, by prepending the path with the '#' character.

Try this as an alterntive:

```
def prefix_file(file):
    return os.path.join(File(file).abspath)
```

Comment: @wvxvw, ok I understand better now. SCons invokes gcc and other compilers the same way and it works. I guess the problem is that tsc needs the absolute path. I'll add a suggestion to the answer.